# how to pass params to bash file from terraform

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, terraform, terraform-provider-oci

I am using cloud-init to run commands on my instance using user-data. I want to create password for jupyter notebook that I want to start as systemd.

this is my terraform main.tf

```
resource "oci_core_instance" "jupyterlab_instance" {
  metadata = {
    ssh_authorized_keys = var.ssh_public_key_file
    user_data           = base64encode(file(var.bootstrap_file) "123456")
  }
```

bootstrap.sh

```
function systemd_jupyter_instance() {
  echo "setting up systemd for jupyter at localhost:8888"

#  password=$(python -c "from IPython.lib.security import passwd; print(passwd('PASS'))")
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/jupyterInst.service
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter instance

[Service]
User=opc
Group=opc
WorkingDirectory=/etc/jupyter/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --NotebookApp.password=$1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl is-active --quiet jupyterInst && sudo systemctl stop jupyterInst
sudo systemctl enable --now jupyterInst
sudo systemctl status jupyterInst

}

function main() {
  systemd_jupyter_instance
}

main
```

I have tried this and I cannot have space while passing user_data. I have tried `remote-exec` provisioner but having issues connecting to my instance because I will have to pass my private key in .tf which I want to avoid.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Typically the shebang `#!/bin/bash` is what tells cloud-init to process the user data as a script. Your function takes an arg but you are not passing an arg. I think this is what you're looking for: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file

Comment: Which value do you want to pass, `123456`? And where would it be used in the script, i.e., what needs to consume that value?

Comment: yes, `123456` is the value that I need to pass. it will be used to configure jupyter instance password in bash script.

Comment: Aside: `function funcname() {` merges the POSIX-standardized syntax `funcname() {` and the 1980s-ksh syntax `function funcname {` in a way that's incompatible with **both** POSIX sh and 1980s ksh (and also semantically compatible with ksh, which changes how `typeset` works inside functions based on the declaration mode). See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would suggest using the `templatefile` built-in function [1]. In order to do that, there has to be a slight modification in both the resource and the user data script. In the resource block, it has to be changed to:

```
resource "oci_core_instance" "jupyterlab_instance" {
  metadata = {
    ssh_authorized_keys = var.ssh_public_key_file
    user_data           = base64encode(tamplatefile(var.bootstrap_file, 
       password = "123456"
   ))
  }
```

Then, in the file itself, you would have to remove `$1` and add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

systemd_jupyter_instance() {
  echo "setting up systemd for jupyter at localhost:8888"

#  password=$(python -c "from IPython.lib.security import passwd; print(passwd('PASS'))")
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/jupyterInst.service
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter instance

[Service]
User=opc
Group=opc
WorkingDirectory=/etc/jupyter/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --NotebookApp.password=${password}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl is-active --quiet jupyterInst && sudo systemctl stop jupyterInst
sudo systemctl enable --now jupyterInst
sudo systemctl status jupyterInst

}

main() {
  systemd_jupyter_instance
}

main
```

Usually, the filename would have a `.tpl` extension to indicate it is a template.

EDIT: As per comments, added the shebang at the start of the template.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

Comment: thanks @marko this was the closest answer that helped. I got it working by defining templatefile in the local

```
bootstrap_configure_file = templatefile(var.bootstrap_file, {
    jp_password = var.jp_password
  })
```

in compute:

```
metadata = {
    ssh_authorized_keys = var.ssh_public_key_file
    user_data           = base64encode(local.bootstrap_configure_file)
  }
```